# Reference request: recurrence relation for Catalan numbers

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, recurrences, catalan-numbers, citations

I would like to know if the following recurrence relation for Catalan numbers (see [mathoverflow.net/questions/191524](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191524/a-recurrence-relation-on-catalan-numbers) and also [math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113830](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113830/recurrence-relation-for-catalan-numbers)) has appeared in a paper or a book, so that I can cite it.

$$C_n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2} \right\rceil
}  (-1)^{k+1} \binom{n-k}{k} C_{n-k}$$
where $C_n$ is the $n$-th Catalan number.

Fixed error: added + 1 to the right hand side

Comment: This will certainly appear in one of the two volumes of Stanley's "Enumerative Combinatorics", which have enormous lists of facts about Catalan numbers.  But my copies are in my office, which I have not visited for a year.

Comment: I looked around in EC a bit and couldn’t find it. The proof given by Ira Gessel is very immediate so I’m not sure a reference is really required...

Comment: Stanley has been known to answer questions here on occasion: https://mathoverflow.net/users/2807/richard-stanley

Comment: Have you checked https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139871495?

Comment: @LuisFerroni: that book also does not contain so much by way of identities satisfied by Catalan numbers; rather it focuses on combinatorial (and algebraic, geometric, etc.) interpretations of Catalan numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

T. Koshy, *Catalan Numbers with Applications* (Oxford, 2009), [page 322](https://books.google.com/books?id=o50RDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA322), proves a very similar identity:
$$C_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}(-1)^{k-1} \binom{n-k+1}{k} C_{n-k}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}  (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n-k+1}{k} C_{n-k}=0.$$
(I did not check the book, the identity is quoted in this [paper,](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/4/2/35) equation 4.)

I also note that Mathematica knows the identity in the OP, in the form

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2} \right\rceil
}  (-1)^{k+1} \binom{n-k}{k} C_{n-k}=-1,$$
(Floor or ceiling in the summation limits does not matter, the sum may also be extended to infinity, since the binomial coefficients vanish.)

---

In response to a question in the comment, I record the q-analog of Koshy's identity, derived by [George Andrews.](http://www.personal.psu.edu/gea1/pdf/275.pdf)

[image]

(The sum over $r$ may be terminated at $\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor$.)

Comment: In fact the first identity you write is the one from the linked MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191524/a-recurrence-relation-on-catalan-numbers (see $n$ vs. $n-1$).

Comment: And probably the 2nd identity is what you get from subtracting the 1st identity for $n$ from the 1st identity for $n-1$, or something like that.

Comment: Is there a q-analog of this identity?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson --- yes there is, I added it.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Ah, that's great! I tried a bit to find it by experimentation, but that last factor is not super obvious.